# How would I find the time complexity of the following recursive algorithm?

Tags: recursion, tree, max, time-complexity, tree-traversal

Assuming that r is the root of a tree (may be non-binary), c is a child of r, and each node contains an integer.

```
Algorithm findMax(r)
if r = null return null
int maxValue = r.value
if r.isLeaf return maxValue;
for each child c of r do{
    if findMax(c) > maxValue
        maxValue = findMax(c)
}
return maxValue
```

Comment: What are your own thoughts on this? Also, did you mean `maxValue = findMax(c)` and `if findMax(c) > maxValue`?

Comment: I think that it would be O(n^2) however the part I am unsure of is that the number of children for each node could be different.

Comment: @BenTilden Does my post answer you?

Comment: Yes thank you @DavidWinder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it does have O(n) complexity when consider `n` to be number of node in the **tree**.

For each child-node of the root you call recursive function to all sub-tree root in `c`. So basically, you preform DFS on this graph which make in O(V+E) -> in your case, when the graph is a tree, it equel to O(V).

Notice, that you call recursive function of `findMax` in the if-statement - if it true you calculate it again - which increase complexity to O(2*n). Calculate the `findMax` function once, assign its result to local var and check and update the `maxValue` with it will reduce complexity to O(n).